# Add binding error messages to custom messages in input tag

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am playing with the Spring [validating form input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) example - java spring mvc with Thymeleaf views.  I have been able to pass messages into the view without issue.  These display where the example wants them to...

e.g.

```
<td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
```

I am trying to find a way to put them into the html input validation attributes though so I have tried the following (full page below)

```
<td><input type="text" th:field="*{age}" **required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="${#fields.errors('age')}" data-errormessage="${#fields.errors('age')}"**/></td>
```

This has done no good though and the validation message displayed is ${#fields.errors('age')} !  Is there a way to push the binding errors into the attribute or am I misunderstanding the way it works ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Page html

```
<html>
```

```
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="Custom Message" /></td>

                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{age}" required="required" data-errormessage-value-missing="${#fields.errors('age')}" data-errormessage="${#fields.errors('age')}"/></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Age Error</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymeleaf only evaluates attributes that start with **th:**, so in order to do this, you have to use **th:attr**.  You're tag should look like:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{age}" required="required" th:attr="data-errormessage-value-missing=${#fields.errors('age')}, data-errormessage=${#fields.errors('age')}" />
```

You could also use this plugin to evaluate data tags, but I've haven't used it before so I can't comment on how well it works: https://github.com/mxab/thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute

Comment: Hi,  Many thanks for this.  It hasn't quite solved the problem but has pointed me in the right direction.  the th:attr attribute does seem correct but my code doesn't pick out an error message.  An if errors exist then print a line of text works so it must be possible to query the binding errors object but I haven't managed to get hold of a specific message yet!  I have stopped for now and believe you answered the crux of the question though (this comment is in case anyone wonders later why I have marked it as an answer but the actual line of code doesn't work!)  Thanks again.